# How do I set a cookie with an expiration time of 3 minutes, and, if the user refreshes the page, it shows "TIMEOUT"?

Tags: php, cookies

I want to set a cookie from my `index.php` with a expiration time of 3 minutes and, if the user refreshes the page, it should show `USER TIMEOUT`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE['SomeThing']))
{
echo "USER TIMEOUT.";
}
else
  $value = "some value";
  setcookie("SomeThing", $value, time()+180);
}
```

Comment: its not displaying timeout 

I WANT TO DISPLAY TIMEOUT TO THE USER IF HE REFRESHES THE PAGE

Comment: please check again @AyuShi, may be you haven't used my updated code and also delete all the comments because its looking like a discussion

Answer (score 0):

In the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) youll find a very clear description on how to set a cookie and its expiry time. 
In a session you could store the number of times a page has loaded, and if it has loaded before, you just block the content of the site and write 'expired'. Note that once your cookie expires, the user can open the page again after closing the page (And thus the session). Along these lines:

```
<?php
session_start();

// reload prevention
if(!isset($_SESSION['pageload']))
  {
  $_SESSION['pageload'] = 1;
  }
else
  {
  echo "USER TIMEOUT.";
  }

if(!isset($_COOKIE['SomeThing']))
  {
  echo "USER TIMEOUT.";
  }
else
  {
  $value = "some value";
  setcookie("SomeThing", $value, time()+180);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this [Expires the cookie every 180 Seconds i.e. Every 3 minutes

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE['TestCookie']))
{
echo "Cookie Not Set.. Setting...";
$value = 'something from somewhere';
setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+180);
}
else
{
echo $_COOKIE['TestCookie'];
}
```